# Are there constructs in Kotlin similar to Swift's #function, #file and #line?

Tags: kotlin

I have a logging function in a Swift class of mine with the following signature:

```
fun logDetails(msg: String, function: String = #function, file: String = #file, line: Int = #line) {
```

I like the fact that I can call it from anywhere in my code, and it will fill in the function, file and source code line where it was called.

Is there any way to accomplish this in Kotlin?

Comment: There is nothing like this in Kotlin to my knowledge

Comment: The one I would find most useful is the line number. How about in Java?

Comment: The Java language doesn't have something like that either (at least to my knowledge, of course). However, in both Kotlin and Java you can access the current stacktrace to get information such as method call stack with files, methods, and line numbers, by using `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` - but that's usually costly

Comment: In practice, logging is probably the only real use case for needing this information — and most Java/Kotlin logging frameworks already take care of it automatically (providing the class name, filename, and line number along with the thread name, time, and other information that can be shown with each log entry). So there's little need for anything else.

Comment: Please see my comment to @Joffrey's answer for when I want the info and it isn't provided by the Java/Kotlin frameworks. In my Swift code, I can write log entries to a log file when it's not harmful to my apps' performance to do so.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct language feature in Kotlin (that I know of) that could do what you want in a similar way.

The only thing along those lines that I can think of in Kotlin/JVM (or Java) is to use [Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getStackTrace()). This returns an array of [StackTraceElement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackTraceElement.html)s that represent the call stack of the current thread. Each of those elements can provide information about filename, class name, method name and line number.

The problem is that computing such stack traces is costly, so I wouldn't use that extensively for extensive logging purposes (unless you're trying to temporarily debug something without access to a debugger).

Comment: The way that my Swift Logger class is useful is for finding an intermittent problem, which may occur when I don't have access to the debugger. However, getStackTrace may still be helpful to me if the cost isn't too high. So, I appreciate the info!